# Black background displays at the JTextFields after priting to PDF with itext

Tags: java, swing, itext

This problem relates to itext with java. After printing the contents of a JFrame, the black background surrounds the `JTextFields`. My question is HOW do i remove the black spots surrounding the text fields?

Here the `JTextfields` have a background color after printing with itext which looks dull to the entire PDF:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
try {
                    Document doc = new Document();
                    JComponent com = jPanel2;

                    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream("Invoice.pdf"));
                    doc.open();

                    PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
                    PdfTemplate template = cb.createTemplate(PageSize.A4.getWidth(), PageSize.A4.getHeight());
                    cb.addTemplate(template, 0, 0);

                    Graphics2D g2d = template.createGraphics(PageSize.A4.getWidth(), PageSize.A4.getHeight());
                    g2d.scale(0.8, 0.8);

                    for (int i = 0; i < this.getContentPane().getComponents().length; i++) {
                        com = (JComponent) this.getContentPane().getComponent(i);
                        g2d.translate(com.getBounds().x, com.getBounds().y);
                        com.paintAll(g2d);
                        com.addNotify();
                    }
                    g2d.dispose();
                    doc.close();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
                }
```

Comment: How is the UI setup? How are you printing it? Maybe consider providing a runnable example which demonstrates your problem in a replicable way

Comment: Thanks @MadProgrammer kindly check the code above.